# C#, patterns - many conditions

Tags: c#, design-patterns, pattern-matching, conditional-statements

I am looking for a good pattern for my problem.

I have some bool variables:

`condition1`, `condition2`, `condition3`.

Also I have some actions, which are called in different places inside a class:

`action1`, `action2`, `action3`

`action1` is called when conditions 1 and 2 are true.
`action2` is called when conditions 2 and 3 are true.
`action3` is called when all conditions are true.

Of course this is just a simplification of the problem. I don't want to use if else in every place. It is terribly unclear.

I have been thinking about state but I guess it's not best solution for this problem.

Comment: So you want a logical structure, that, when you run it, follow your explanations?

Comment: Patterns? Design patterns are not conditional statements mate ;)

Comment: make one static method that takes those bool vars and return correct Action...

Comment: @TusharGupta unless we are talking about the Interpreter patter. Or Command. Or Composite. In all of them one of the samples is composing a complex condition. But they aren't suitable here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Op mentioned and tagged design patterns and asking a replacement of if-else and Also he interpreter design pattern allow us to take the rules of a language and build them as classes. ;)

Comment: In fact, there is such a thing, although it predates patterns. You are asking for a truth table whose first three columns containt the condition combinations and fourth column an *Action<T>*. You could probably use a Dictionary<int,Action<T>> whose key would be the bitwise OR of the flags

Comment: just include your code.... how you see it, then SO can see how it can be changed... to look nicer.

Comment: @TusharGupta exactly. And one of the examples in the *original pattern* was complex logical expressions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : So are ok with using something like DFS in place of if-else for such small cause ?

Comment: "Action1 is called when conditions 1 and 2 are true". Does it also need condition3 to be false?

Comment: [Replace your conditions with polymorphism](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism). Show us your code if you want pointers on how to refactor.

Comment: -1'd the answers that suggested how the OP would abstractly hammer conditions into their code, rather than say... designing things well. Read the link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to wrap the condition logic in a base class and then derive from it to execute the actual actions. The is a variation on the [Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern and (I think) the [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern:

```
class ActionState
{
  public bool Condition1{get;set;}
  public bool Condition2{get;set;}
  public bool Condition3{get;set;}
}

abstract class ActionDispatcher
{
  protected abstract void ExecuteAction1();
  protected abstract void ExecuteAction2();
  protected abstract void ExecuteAction2();

  public void Action1(ActionState state)
  {
    if(state.Condition1 && state.Condition2)
    {
      ExecuteAction1();
    }
  }

  public void Action2(ActionState state)
  {
    if(state.Condition2 && state.Condition3)
    {
      ExecuteAction2();
    }
  }

  public void Action3(ActionState state)
  {
    if(state.Condition1 && state.Condition2 && state.Condition3)
    {
      ExecuteAction3();
    }
  }

  public void AllActions(ActionState state)
  {
    // Execute all actions depending on the state
    Action1(state);
    Action2(state);
    Action3(state);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to know who downvoted a variation of Command? Do we *really* have to dig out the GOF copies and reference *pages* ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is GOF really worth the read if you're a C# developer? I saw the examples are only C++ (sorry for going off-topic)

Comment: This can be made more generic. Eg, a single class could be used. The condition can become a `Func<bool>` field or property, the action an Action<T>. In fact, that's how many workflow systems work (including WF).

Comment: @AlexanderDerck if you only show the examples, then you haven't read it. and only know a third-person summary of the patterns. Patterns are *not* the code, they are the problem, context, solution and the relations to other patterns. Several features of current languages like C# *are* implementations of those patterns. Knowing them will help you combine them in new ways

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So it's written in a form that's not too language-specific? That's what I needed to know because I see a lot of people recommending it :)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck some examples are in Smalltalk, some in C++. It just doesn't matter. It's the concepts that *really* matter, the description of the problems, solutions etc. You can easily find implementations of the various patterns in your favourite language once you understand what you are looking for

Comment: Hm, I think  this is what I need. In this case, probably it's not possible to remove if statements. However it will help keep code clearer.

Comment: what if we have tens of conditions and more complex logic (a1 && (a2 || a3) && !(a4 && (a5 || a6)) ...)?

Answer (score 3):

You might be helped by an `enum` with the `[Flags]` attribute, instead of separate booleans. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480/1220550) for a very good explanation + examples.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are not hugely well defined, but it sounds like a map of states to actions, where a state is defined by a number of simple conditions, and each state only has one action. So why not actually represent it like that?

Here's a simple LinqPad example:

```
void Main()
{   
    Dictionary<Cond, Action> d = new Dictionary<Cond, Action>()  
    {
        { new Cond(waterproof:true, shockproof:true, freezeproof:false), delegate() { "Action1".Dump(); } },
        { new Cond(waterproof:false, shockproof:true, freezeproof:true), delegate() { "Action2".Dump(); } },
        { new Cond(waterproof:true, shockproof:true, freezeproof:true), delegate() { "Action3".Dump(); } }
    };

    d[new Cond(true, true, false)]();
    d[new Cond(false, true, true)]();
    d[new Cond(true, true, true)]();
}

public class Cond : Tuple<bool, bool, bool>
{
    public Cond(bool waterproof, bool shockproof, bool freezeproof) : base(waterproof, shockproof, freezeproof)
    {
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Action1
Action2
Action3
```

The subclass of `Tuple<>` is because:

1. It makes everything much more readable rather than having the generic arguments everywhere.
2. You can use named parameters as I have done to make the map logic very clear.
3. You can swap it out with a custom class if you need more complex logic, like varying numbers of conditions in each state.

You will probably need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in that case.

(You obviously don't need to use the anonymous delegates; you can just pass a direct reference to the method you want to use)

Answer (score 0):

You might implement visitor Pattern. But it depends on you level abstraction and your functionnalities 
[Visitor Pattern Implementation example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12508/Dude-are-you-still-programming-using-if-then-else)

Comment: Visitor pattern is used for trees of objects, I don't see how it would help here

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/158761)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can implement it without any if clause.

You can transform this boolean in a integer which allows you get the method in a dictionary, for example:

`cond1 = false, cond2 = true, cond3 = false`

you can transform this in:
`0 + 1 + 0` = 1

then, you will create a key for every solution you have, as follow:

```
public Class Action1: IAction;
public Class Action2: IAction;
public Class Action3: IAction;

Dictionary<int, IAction> dict = new Dictionary<int, IAction>()
{
    6, new Action1(); //110
    3, new Action2(); //011
    7, new Action3(); //111
};
```

IAction interface:

```
public interface IAction
{
    void execute();
}
```

And inside each method `execute()` in concrete class, you will implement each action.

Then you will execute your action by simply:

```
key = //transform binary in decimal
dict[key].execute();
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

It could be an extension method:

```
public static void WhenTrue(this bool condition, Action action)
{
    if (action == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    if (condition)
        action();
}
```

usage:

```
(condition1 && condition2).WhenTrue(() => DoSomeWork(param1));
```

But this only makes sense when you have a lot of conditions and a lot of actions to keep the code cleaner.

Comment: How is that any better from saying `if(condition1 && condition2) DoSomeWork(param1);` ?

Comment: To be honest, it's not. However, if you change `void` to `bool` then it would be possible to chain... Although still pretty stupid :) Maybe the OP can think of something base on that =)